# Can I make a matrix row group span its child groups in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a matrix, whose rows are grouped into two groups. A class, and a time for that class. The class cell is going to end up being several lines long, and I'd like the rows for each time slot of the class to line up next to the class description, like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
**Class**         | 7:00am  | [row data]
Description of    |----------------------
the class, this   | 12:00pm | [row data]
is several lines  |----------------------
long.             | 1:00pm  | [row data]
-----------------------------------------
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
-----------------------------------------
**Class**         | 7:00am  | [row data]
Description of    |         |
the class, this   |         |
is several lines  |         |
long.             |         |
-----------------------------------------
                  | 12:00pm | [row data]
                  |         |
                  |         |
                  |         |
                  |         |
-----------------------------------------
                  | 1:00pm  | [row data]
                  |         |
                  |         |
                  |         |
                  |         |
-----------------------------------------
```

Is there any way to make SSRS collapse the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with so far:

1. Create a List.
2. Add a details group to the list for the outermost row group (Class in this example).
3. Populate the list with the contents of the outermost row (Class, and its long description).
4. Add a Matrix to the list.
5. Populate the Matrix with the remaining groups (Time and the row data in this example).

The Matrix will correlate itself to the containing list automatically, so each class will only display the times associated with it.

This DOES make generating the headers problematic (they repeat with each List iteration). I'm still trying to figure that part out.